# chemmacros extra space after \state

Tags: spacing, chemmacros

I am using the `chemmacros` package and the `\state[subscript-left=r]{H}` command. It does produce the standard enthalpy of reaction symbol perfectly, however when used inline in a sentence there is an unsightly space afterwards. Is there any way of gobbling up this space to make it look neater other than putting in `\(\!\!\!\)`? See the difference between the two in the 2nd line of the attached graphic...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{thermodynamics}
\begin{document}
Write an expression showing how to calculate the enthalpy of reaction,
\state[subscript-left=r]{H}, from the enthalpies of formation,
\state[subscript-left=f]{H}\(\!\!\), explaining each of the parameters.
\end{document}
```

[image: state_spacing]

Comment: Is using `\negmedspace` or `\negthickspace` preferable?

Comment: I suppose what I’m really asking is is there a modification that can be made to the \state command so one doesn’t need to put in this correction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chemmacros` does not really insert space after the state symbol as the first to lines in the following example show.

You *can* set up the macro to insert a negative kern afterwards but this might have unwanted effects in other places (see the example). I would adjust manually where needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{thermodynamics}

\begin{document}

xxx\state[subscript-left=r]{H}xxx

xxx$\Delta_{\text{r}}H^\standardstate$xxx

\state[subscript-left=r]{H}\kern-.3em,

\chemsetup{
  thermodynamics/post = \kern-.3em
}

\state[subscript-left=r]{H}, \state[subscript-left=r]{H}xxx

\end{document}
```

[image]